# I ran into the same grub issue of not being able to install grub, but have an answer

Tags: linux, boot, grub

When I was trying to install Kali 2020 from the live ISO, I selected the Graphical install, so I end up with the grub install problem.

Start again and switch to the text base install and all goes well with zero issues.

I ran into this twice, there is something about the graphical installation that causes the problem, install using text based installation, not as pretty but works good.

Comment: I’m voting to close as this is not a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [‘Iinstall the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk’’ failed on my PC](https://superuser.com/questions/1195075/install-the-grub-boot-loader-on-a-hard-disk-failed-on-my-pc)

Comment: Or perhaps [Kali installation stuck at Install the GRUB boot loader](https://superuser.com/q/1200297/150988)

Comment: We allow people to answer the same question's they've asked, but we expect the question and the answer to be placed into their appropriate and clearly indicated places in the site. Answers posted as questions are not allowed.